# How can I accept an answer on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Last time I asked a question, I got a reply stating that because I don't accept answers given by other users, users may think that I am not getting reluctant answers. Can anyone just tell me how I can accept answers which have resolved my queries? I can't find any link on a Stack Overflow page where I can accept answers given by users.

Comment: [See the FAQ!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about)